# ListView Item Onclick Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

Good Day, I'm making a listview item `onClick` in fragment. Every time I click the other item it shows the same fragment activity. What should I do to to make it different from the other item? Should I use

> `if (postion==0)` or Case?

**List1TW**

```
public List1TW() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list1_tw, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        String[] awayStrings = {
                "Chocolate Hills",
                "Banaue Rice Terraces",
                "Hinatuan Enchanted River",
                "Mount Mayon",
                "Puerto Princesa Underground River",
                "Lake Sebu",
                "Sumaguing Cave",
                "Tinuy-an Falls",
        };

        ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView2);

        ArrayAdapter<String> lva = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, awayStrings);
        lv.setAdapter(lva);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                TW1 fragment = new TW1();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();

            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: what do you want ?? different fragments for different clicks?? If so where are the other fragments?

Comment: Because in `onItemClick` method you are always adding `TW1 ` Fragment .

Comment: instead of using String for `awayStrings`, you can use object with 2 attribute: one is value with string type and one is FragmentType. Then you define Map of FragmentType and Fragment you wanna show. Whenever user click on item, you just getFragmentType and how corresponding fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `position` variable

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            if(position == 0){
            TW1 fragment = new TW1();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
       }
   else if(){
      }
   //// or even switch
  switch(position){
     case 1:
     // do your work
      break;          
       }
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want identify position click you can use Case over here in itemclickListener. Or you can set position with fragment using bundle and then identify clicked position in Fragment as well.

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("position", position);
                    TW1 fragment = new TW1();
                    fragment.setArgument(bundle);
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();

                }
            });
```