# Add Fragment when item is clicked in adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, listview, android-fragments, adapter

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863151/listview-item-onclick-fragment) but could not find the answer.

I simply want to add `Fragment` when any item from `listView` is clicked. I tried to access `getSupportFragmentManager` to implement Fragment but couldn't access it. I instantiated `FragmentActivity` class and then called `supportFragmentManager`. Now facing above following error.

*java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager has not been attached to a host.*

**Kindly tell me where I'm doing wrong.**

```
class AnimalAdapter : BaseAdapter {
        var context: Context
        var listOfAnimals: List<Animal>? = null

        constructor(listOfAnimals: List<Animal>?, context: Context) : super() {
            this.listOfAnimals = listOfAnimals
            this.context = context
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return listOfAnimals!!.size
        }

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
            return listOfAnimals?.get(position)!!
        }

        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()
        }

        @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
            val animal = listOfAnimals?.get(position)

            val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            val rowView: View
            if (animal?.isKiller!!) {
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_killer_animal_ticket, parent, false)
            }
            else{
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.animal_ticket, parent, false)
            }
            val imageAnimal = rowView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_animal)
            val textNameAnimal = rowView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_animal_name)
            val textAnimalDesc = rowView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_animal_description)

            imageAnimal.setImageResource(animal?.image!!)
            textNameAnimal.text = animal.name
            textAnimalDesc.text = animal.des

            rowView.setOnClickListener{

                val fragmentActivity = FragmentActivity()

                fragmentActivity.supportFragmentManager.commit {
                    val fragmet: Fragment = AnimalDescriptionFragment()
                    replace(R.id.animal_desc_fragment_contianer, fragmet)
                    addToBackStack("animal_desc_frag")
                }

            }



            return rowView
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you simply can't create local `Activity` (`val fragmentActivity = FragmentActivity()`), its just some memory alocation, but this `Activity` is dead. You have to keep reference to already existing and shown `Activity`, which is containing your adapter

instead of `var context: Context` in your constructor use `var fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity` and then you may use `fragmentActivity.supportFragmentManager.commit...` - simply keep reference to alive `Activity`, not freshly created object

Comment: much appreciated, my problem got solved. is there any other way to access `supportFragmentManager`  than this?

Comment: `supportFragmentManager` belongs to `Activity`, so if you want to use this class in somewhere else you have to pass reference to it, there is no other method. you may edit constructor and split `FragmentActivity` reference to two: `Context` and `FragmentManager`, but result will be the same

Comment: if `supportFragmentManager` belongs to `Activity` then why we can not access it by simply 'context`  e.g: `context.supportFragmentManager`?

Comment: `Activity extends Context` and `FragmentManager` is added on this layer, not present in basic `Context`. few more classes are also extending `Context`, like `Service` or `Application`, and these objects can't use `FragmentManager`, they don't have GUI

Comment: you should pass WeakReference to that activity for keeping the activity reference in your adapter

Answer (score 1):

Honestly you should keep this stuff separate - an adapter is there to turn a data set into some kind of visual display, it shouldn't be directly controlling other parts of the app's UI, messing with the backstack etc.

Ideally you'd have some kind of listener you can update when an item is clicked. That's it, the adapter just goes "hey this got clicked", maybe provide some specifics about it, and it's up to the listeners (if any) to decide what to do with that.

Probably the best thing to use is a `ViewModel` - pass that in to the adapter, have a `currentItem` `LiveData` value that it can set, and then other components can `observe` that value and react to it. The adapter doesn't need to know anything about what they're up to.

The quick and dirty way is to just have a method on the parent `Activity`, like `onAnimalItemClicked()`, pass that in to the `Adapter`, and call the method when you need to. You'll need to use the specific Activity class unless you create an interface for the method that your Activity implements. It's not ideal (and you always have to watch out for memory leaks when keeping a reference to something like an Activity) but it gets the job done